# Sort a child relationship by a grandchild value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this Ticket model:

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TicketItem', 'ticket_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and the TicketItem model:

```
class TicketItem extends Model {    
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
    }
}
```

and the Product model:

```
class Product extends Model {   
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }
}
```

Product has a field called `category_id`.

When I do a `App\Models\Ticket::find(123)->load('items.product.category')` I want `ticket.items` to be sorted by `ticket.items.product.category_id.`

Comment: Our AngularJS app has a simple filter: `ng-repeat="item in ticket.items | orderBy: 'product.category_id'"`. I am looking to achieve this server side.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
App\Models\Ticket::find(123)->load(['items' => function($query) {
  $query->join('products', 'product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC');
})->load('items.product.category');
```

This will tell Eloquent, that when **items** are loaded, additional criteria from the callback should be applied. In there, you join items with products and sort items by **category_id**.

**UPDATE:** To avoid conflicts in column names, you can use aliases for table names:

```
App\Models\Ticket::find(123)->load(['items' => function($query) {
  $query->from('ticket_items as tis')
    ->join('products as ps', DB::raw('its.product_id'), '=', DB::raw('ps.id'))
    ->select(DB::raw('tis.*'))
    ->orderBy('category_id', 'ASC');
})->load('items.product.category');
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.4 this join is overwriting the `TicketItem.id` to be the `Product.id`. Any other way?

Comment: Oh, right. That's a know issue. With Laravel 5.1 I had to use custom primary key names for some of the models just to get joins to work. I've updated the answer to use table aliases, let me know if that helps

Comment: is there a way of doing this directly from the top model relationship? so that the `ticket.items` are always ordered by `product.category_id`?

Comment: You should be simply able toappend the same constraints to your relation definition, e.g. $this->hasMany(...)->from(...)->join(...)->....

Comment: Any idea if this would be a big resource drain?

Comment: You can have 2 differently named relations in your model, one with join and another one without, if you’re worried about performance.